# How would one use Nginx to proxy uploads to S3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, nginx, amazon-s3

I want to upload files to S3 while masking the S3 bucket name / authentication headers. From my understanding, I can do this using Nginx.

For example, a user would perform a `POST` request to `http://media.mywebsite.com` which would then pass through Nginx, appending the authentication headers, and uploading the file. Also, I would like to give each file a random and unique name, and return the URL of where the file was uploaded in the response to the user.

How do I do this? Do I need anything else behind Nginx, or can Nginx handle all of this? I have not used Nginx before, so be kind.

Currently, I am uploading files via a multipart request to my Rails server, but this locks up the server for much too long when larger uploads are performed, so I'm trying to bypass Rails.

Comment: you can proxy GET so why not to do that for POST if you can pass required headers to manage S3 authentication

Comment: So just proxy S3 using Nginx? Is it really that simple?

Comment: it requires some work, but you can start there https://coderwall.com/p/rlguog/nginx-as-proxy-for-amazon-s3-public-private-files https://coderwall.com/p/swgfvw/nginx-direct-file-upload-without-passing-them-through-backend

Comment: we do really bypass backend for S3 file upload. Nginx receives a request, dumps file on disk (client body request) and makes a callback through proxy_pass. Callback fires an event on background queue that handles S3 upload via async manner.

Comment: @mikhailov Would you mind sharing your `nginx.conf`?

Comment: already done, see my previous comment

Comment: @mikhailov Oh! I didn't know that was your post. Thank you!

Comment: @mikhailov I've put something together and I'd love to see what you think if you have a few min to check it out. `nginx.conf` is in the config folder. https://github.com/jamescmartinez/nginx-s3-upload

Answer (score -1):

I believe a similar process is explained in https://medium.com/@ayushi.garg.1710/multipart-upload-and-download-with-aws-s3-using-boto3-with-python-using-nginx-proxy-server-bce35f3d5ba6

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.